# why the simplest servelet return the "$END$" when visiting "/"

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am writing the simplest servlet, when running in the tomcat locally using / url, the webpage returns $END$, I would like to know why?

The servlet itself is plain simplest one

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name="Hello" ,urlPatterns={"/Hello"},loadOnStartup=1)
public class Hello extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("Hello world"+"<br />");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: When visiting /, you're not invoking this servlet, since it's mapped to /Hello.

Comment: but why it is returning $END$?